# Javascript don't see diference between 2 textarea ids

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this function:

```
function sendCommand(id, ip, command) {
    var xmlhttp = makeRequestObject();
    var file = 'http://example.com/ajaxaccessdata.php?ip=';
    xmlhttp.open('GET', file + ip + '&command=' + command, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var content = xmlhttp.responseText;
            if (content) {
                document.getElementById('result' + id).value = content;
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(null)
}
```

And i have n textarea with IDs `'result1', 'result2', ..., 'resultn'`.
And when i call function `sendCommand` my function put result in all textarea, so result for `sendCommand(1, 'localhost', 'A')` will be put in all textarea not only in `result`.
Any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: Could you post some JSFiddle with an example (without AJAX requests or mocked)?

Comment: In max 5 minutes, i put a link with jfiddle.

Comment: `document.getElementById('result' + id).value = content;` do you just want your answer in document.getElementById('result').value = content;

Comment: I call from different buttons, like when i call from button1 i want to put content in result1, button2 in result2 .... so i use an unique ID for every set of (button, textarea).

Comment: document.getElementsByName('result' + id)[0].value = content;

Comment: @Shane_Yo There is no getElementByName.....

Comment: Are you sure you are passing in different ids to the method to start? Can you show more code?

Comment: Was my mistake, i was passing a wrong id. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var content = xmlhttp.responseText;
        if (content) {
            var x = document.getElementsByName('result');
            x[id+1].value = content;
        }
     }
}
```